# ManyToOne relation in sonata admin bundle

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I have an entity which DishesWithCategory by the link to other entities:

```
   /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Dishes", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    protected $dishes;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="MenuCategory", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    protected $category;
```

In admin i have:

```
$formMapper
    ->add('dishes', 'sonata_type_admin', [
        'delete' => false,
        'btn_add' => false
    ])
    ->add('category', 'sonata_type_model',[
        'expanded' => true,
        'multiple' => true,
    ])
;
```

When I try to create a dish, I get the error:
**Found entity of type Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection on association ZaWeb\MenuBundle\Entity\DishesWithCategory#category, but expecting ZaWeb\MenuBundle\Entity\MenuCategory**

Can someone faced with this? how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't fully understand your model but i think that the issue comes from : the multiple => true on category because you can set only one category (ManyToOne) for a DishesWithCategory.

Either you need to change your model to a OneToMany for your $category or you need to remove the ArrayCollection which might be in the constructor of your model and remove multiple => true.

You might need to do :

```
$formMapper
    ->add('dishes', 'sonata_type_admin', [
        'delete' => false,
        'btn_add' => false
    ])
    ->add('category', 'sonata_type_model',[
        'expanded' => true
    ])
;
```